# Unit test project takes ~40 seconds to build via nCrunch with MS Fakes

Tags: microsoft-fakes, ncrunch

I've got about 27 tests in a Unit testing project, one of which is using System.Fakes to fake a System.DateTime call.  It seems that the unit test project is recreating the System.Fakes extensions with every build meaning that nCrunch is VERY slow to show unit test results.  I've not experienced this when using rhinomocks for mocking interfaces in tests and I was wondering if there was a way to improve this performance that anyone was aware of when using Microsoft.Fakes.

Comment: Shims are expensive. Stubs aren't bad, especially if you only generate them once and store them. The problem with shims is that they modify the IL at runtime, so they will always be slow. I'm glad you found a way around it, though.

Comment: Yea, I expected a bit of a performance hit, but nothing like I was seeing. I think it was more of a config issue than an expected performance hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allocated an [additional processor](http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/reference_global-configuration_cpu-cores-assigned-to-ncrunch-or-vs) to nCrunch and set the [fastlane thread option](http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/reference_global-configuration_fast-lane-threads) and this made a huge difference.  Tests were as responsive as I've experienced with rhinomocks.  I'm happy.